# Redirect part of a string with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a rule in my .htacess file to replace with an underscore and 301 redirect any part of a querystring that contains the space (%20) or the double space (%2520) character.

So, for example, if a querystring contains the following parameter

```
weight=really%2520really%20heavy
```

The parameter needs to be changed in the URL and redirected to:

```
weight=really_really_heavy
```

I need this as a temporary measure; unfortunately I do not have access to the PHP script that produces these parameters but I am waiting for them to be changed.

I would be grateful for a rule that I can place in my .htacess to do this.

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done with htaccess, you'll need some string-functions which are not available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to match the query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/to/this/directory
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(%20|%2520)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?%1_%3 [N,R=301]
```

Explanation: For the 301 redirect to work, you need to set RewriteBase to the directory containing the .htaccess file (as seen from the web browser, relative to DocumentRoot).

You must set RewriteCond to match the querystring, and choose the pattern to match.

In the replacement pattern in the last line, $1 is a back reference to the RewriteRule pattern, and %1, %3 are back references to the RewriteCond pattern.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Im afraid your code did not work for me. Is an R flag needed somewhere?

Comment: Hey, I just updated my answer with the R flag and the required RewriteBase option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, worked a treat! I did have a problem (it seemed to conflict with a rewrite rule I had that redirects non www to www) but solved this by changing the order of the rules in my .htaccess (moved your rule below non www to www). Now it works fine. Thanks again for your help on this, always appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ $1_$2 [N]
```

should do it (adjusting the options in the brackets to whatever suits you); it replaces the first space with an underscore, then repeats the rule until it doesn't match any more. Note that the backslash-space might not work; in that case, I don't know how to do it since matching spaces in URLs in mod_rewrite is very finicky sometimes.